# JDeveloper alternative for eclipse shortcuts

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, jdeveloper

I've been using eclipse for about 10 years now, and today I will be (forced to) use JDeveloper for the first time.

Being a big fan of the eclipse shortcuts, I would like to know some JDeveloper alternatives for my favorite shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> (Quick access)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>, depending on your keyboard) (Quick Fix)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> (Show the shortcuts :-))
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Add a new line below the current one)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd> (Move line(s))
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd> (Copy line(s))

Any other shortcuts in JDeveloper I should know about? I have found [this link](http://ikool.wordpress.com/2008/06/23/jdeveloper-and-eclipse-shortcuts-compared/), but the list is way too short.

Comment: Wow...I didn't know that JDeveloper was still a serious product.  I feel sorry for you.  :(

Answer (score 16):

I once battled JDeveloper for two years and somehow lived to tell about it.  If you're using 11g, here is a [trick you can use to load the Eclipse shortcut scheme](http://web-center-suite.blogspot.com/2011/08/jdeveloper-shortcuts.html).  I highly recommend doing this as there's really no value in learning the native key bindings.

A second piece of advice, do whatever it takes to get off whatever project you're required to use JDeveloper for. It is an ancient, buggy IDE designed to cater to an [obscure, buggy framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index.html).  You will quickly find yourself handcuffed by JDeveloper and ADF, it is in no way in the same league as Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ.  You **will** hate it. You have been warned.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the official link for JDeveloper shortcuts:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E16162_01/user.1112/e17455/working_jdev.htm#OJDUG159

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I do know how to use google. So no, that didn't really help :)